# New to GCP Firewall issues perhaps? Cant get Server to talk to remote server on port 2086 or 2087

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, cpanel, whm, whmcs

So I decided to put WHMCS onto a GCP system so my billing and support for my clients are separate from my clients so IF a server ever does go down, I won't be down in theory.

Now I am trying to connect it to one of my cpanel servers and I am getting Access Denied. I reached out to WHMCS they tried to help me and blamed it on cpanel firewall. I took the code they gave me and tossed it onto two different cpanel servers and they do not have any issues talking to each other. So then I updated the curl test code on GCP to do BOTH servers same time and both fail... Just to humor it further I turned off both cpanel firewalls and still the same.

I can ssh to either server from either server no issues I just can't seem to get port 2086 or 2087 to work. I made a firewall rule with the remote servers IP and gave it the port range and even opened all ports. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/judcf.png)

Any suggestions? I have been fighting this now for 6 days and can't move forward.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to connect to your VM instance via SSH because it's allowed by [pre-populated rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc):

> Allows ingress connections on TCP port 22 from any source to any
>   instance in the network.

**To allow connections to your WHMCS** follow steps below:

1. [reserve a static external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) address for your VM (you can use it on your on-premises firewall)
2. [set a network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) to your VM (for example `whmcs-server`) and [change external IP to static](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign)
3. [create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall#creating_a_firewall_ingress_rule) that allows incoming traffic to your VM instance from remote server by using network tag
4. check GCP firewall rules from remote server with command `nmap -Pn EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_WHMCS_VM`

*Do not forget* to open required ports on your on-premises firewall for reserved at step 1 external IP and also check from GCP VM if everything configured as expected with command `nmap -Pn EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_REMOTE_SERVER`.

Comment: The first part of your answer is not correct. Rules are processed by priority. The final default rule is a deny. The other rules will be processed one by one until an ALLOW is reached at which time the rule processing stops. Rules with the same priority are still processed.